# shortcut for opening cmd.exe at a certain location

Tags: windows, command-line, script, shell-script

How can I create an icon\shortcut to a script that opens `cmd.exe` command prompt at a certain location on a certain drive under Win7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i don't know in windows 7, but in windows xp and previous:

- create a shortcut to c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
- right-click -> properties
- in the "start in" write the desired target folder (e.g. f:\aviv\geffen)

click ok, and there you go.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question I've asked, however the `/K` based approach in my answer is more flexible, e.g. `cd` somewhere and then run a script or two.

Answer (score 6):

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe, then go to its properties and edit the Target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "D: & cd eclipse"
```

This would first change the current directory to `D:` and then `cd` into `eclipse` folder

Comment: So, you found the answer to your own question then? :)

Comment: Or change the value in the "Start in:" field to the drive and folder you wish to start CMD.EXE in. The default value is `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` which can be configured to be otherwise.

Comment: @Oldskool - yup :)

Comment: A better way of expressing the command would be "cd /d d:\eclipse".

Comment: You should mark this as the answer to the question so people don't attempt to answer it.

Comment: @Ramhound - I think I can only do that after 2 days if I answered my own question. But also - people may have different approaches, perhaps their solution will be better...

Comment: Try mine (originally Oldskool's) it's quicker and easier! :D

Answer (score 5):

Within Windows 7 you can just hold down the Shift key when right clicking a location and the `Open Command Window Here` option will then appear in the right-click menu.  **The starting location (path) is your right-click destination!**

For previous versions of Windows, I came across [this](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/) plug-in which inserts a 'Open Command Prompt' option into the right click menu - it will open it in the current folder/multiple command prompts in multiple locations with just a few clicks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question of doing this from within a script. And furthermore since Win7 there's no need for a plugin, just hold down the Shift key when right clicking a location and the "Open command window here" option will then appear in the menu.

Comment: You should've posted that as an answer then, i'm pretty sure the OP is totally unaware of this feature - as was i. I'll edit my answer to contain it.

Comment: It doesn't read that the OP is using a script, he asked if a script was the solution

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for. Thanks for the tip.